# text format in the appendix in a thesis

Tags: fonts, environments

I am using **Easy Thesis** template from sharelatex.

I need some help to put the text below **as it is** in the appendix section in a thesis. I may prefer the font **as it is** (ascii).

```
REMARK  
ATOM      1   O25 KKM     1      41.799  30.649 -26.049
ATOM      2   C25 KKM     1      41.727  29.258 -25.898
ATOM      3   C24 KKM     1      42.793  28.745 -24.865
ATOM      4   C23 KKM     1      44.141  29.190 -25.292
ATOM      5   C22 KKM     1      44.161  30.728 -25.492
ATOM      6   C21 KKM     1      43.067  31.109 -26.501
ATOM      7   H45 KKM     1      41.975  28.880 -26.848
ATOM      8   H44 KKM     1      42.413  29.086 -23.905
ATOM      9   H43 KKM     1      44.389  28.745 -26.207
ATOM      10  H42 KKM     1      44.006  31.218 -24.523
ATOM      11  H41 KKM     1      43.073  32.210 -26.456
ATOM      12  C26 KKM     1      40.283  28.888 -25.517
END
```

I tried using define new environment as blow

```
\newenvironment{allintypewriter}{\ttfamily}{\par} as given in [here][1]
```

But this did not help.

I get something as below:

```
REMARK ATOM 1 O25 KKM 1 41.799 30.649 -26.049 ATOM 2 C25
KKM 1 41.727 29.258 -25.898 ATOM 3 C24 KKM 1 42.793
28.745 -24.865 ATOM 4 C23 KKM 1 44.141 29.190 -25.292
ATOM 5 C22 KKM 1 44.161 30.728 -25.492 ATOM 6 C21 KKM 1
43.067 31.109 -26.501 ATOM 7 H45 KKM 1 41.975 28.880
-26.848 ATOM 8 H44 KKM 1 42.413 29.086 -23.905 ATOM 9 H43
KKM 1 44.389 28.745 -26.207 ATOM 10 H42 KKM 1 44.006
31.218 -24.523 ATOM 11 H41 KKM 1 43.073 32.210 -26.456
ATOM 12 C26 KKM 1 40.283 28.888 -25.517 END
```

The data is not arranged in a column order.

Could I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "as-it-is environment" is environment is given by `verbatim`:

```
\begin{verbatim}
REMARK  
ATOM      1   O25 KKM     1      41.799  30.649 -26.049
ATOM      2   C25 KKM     1      41.727  29.258 -25.898
ATOM      3   C24 KKM     1      42.793  28.745 -24.865
ATOM      4   C23 KKM     1      44.141  29.190 -25.292
ATOM      5   C22 KKM     1      44.161  30.728 -25.492
ATOM      6   C21 KKM     1      43.067  31.109 -26.501
ATOM      7   H45 KKM     1      41.975  28.880 -26.848
ATOM      8   H44 KKM     1      42.413  29.086 -23.905
ATOM      9   H43 KKM     1      44.389  28.745 -26.207
ATOM      10  H42 KKM     1      44.006  31.218 -24.523
ATOM      11  H41 KKM     1      43.073  32.210 -26.456
ATOM      12  C26 KKM     1      40.283  28.888 -25.517
END
\end{verbatim}
```

If you wish to enable certain formatting options (although it's not mentioned in your question), you can consider using [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb).